# Determine running classes and jar's from Linux ps output

Tags: java, bash, process

My goal is to list to STDOUT the class files and .jar files being executed by java on a Linux server.  I could do some getopts thing to get args to -jar, but other processes identified by

ps -ef | grep java    or  ps -eo args | grep java

might be executing a class file, e.g. java -classpath /a/b/c myclass A1 A2 .  I am concerned that I am looking at an inelegant solution full of lengthy piplines of greps and awk's to solve what should be (I think) a straightforward query.  Given that:

1. some calls are made to just 'java' and others to the fully qualified pathname for java,
2. a variety of different (or no) java options may be set on the command line for running a process,
3. some processes call .jar files, some call .class files, and
4. there may be args to the class,

what is the best way to get a simple list of running java executables, like:

abc.jar

mymainclass

xyz.jar

numainclass

I think that this may be a not uncommon question, but I can't seem to build a search string that locates any previous discussion here.  An elegant solution would be nice; right now I am looking at grepping '-jar' entries to a getops call, and parsing the remainder considering all possible combinations.  I am working on a solution in bash 3.x

Thanks!

Comment: You can use JVisualVM that comes with JDK [http://visualvm.java.net/description.html](http://visualvm.java.net/description.html). But, you need to set up JMX support in your app see `Enabling JMX access in the target VM` section in the given link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [jps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jps.html) command introduced in jdk5 might be what you are looking for. Using the  `-l` and `-m` options it will output the pid main class and arguments. Adding `-v` will add the vm arguments.

Comment: We actually ended up writing a bash parser, but if we had not done so, this would have been out solution of choice.  Thanks Jorn.

Answer (score 0):

This option lists all Java files currently *opened* by a `java` command. Maybe it is useful to you.

```
lsof | grep -E "^java.*(.jar|.class)$" | sed -E "s/\s+/\t/g" | cut -f9
```

It works in Debian.