# How to find Kafka server properties file for an running broker

Tags: apache-kafka

how to locate the path of server.properties which was used to start the Kafka broker.

Tried doing ps -ef | grep -I Kafka, not seeing the server.properties location file

Checked the broker log, its has all the properties, but not the property file location.

need to find the location of properties file which was used, so I can restart the broker with correct config file.

ps -ef output:

`403 root      0:32 java -Xmx1G -Xms1G -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:MaxInlineLevel=15 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xlog:gc*:file=/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../logs/kafkaServer-gc.log:time,tags:filecount=10,filesize=100M -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dkafka.logs.dir=/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../logs -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../config/log4j.properties -cp /opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/activation-1.1.1.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/commons-cli-1.4.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/connect-api-3.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/connect-basic-auth-extension-3.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/connect-file-3.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/connect-json-3.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-3.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/connect-mirror-client-3.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/connect-runtime-3.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/connect-transforms-3.0.0.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/hk2-api-2.6.1.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/hk2-locator-2.6.1.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/hk2-utils-2.6.1.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations-2.12.3.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/jackson-core-2.12.3.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/jackson-databind-2.12.3.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/jackson-dataformat-csv-2.12.3.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.12.3.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.12.3.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.12.3.jar:/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0`

Comment: The ps output doesn't show the arguments the main class was started with (which includes the properties file)?

Comment: Nope, edited the original question with ps -ef output

Comment: That output is cutoff since it doesn't include the main class or arguments. Try `ps aux`, but also `/opt/kafka_2.13-3.0.0/config` would be the default location

Comment: ps aux didnt help, yes agree on the default path, but if we have multiple properties file under the same location how do i know which file was last used to start the broker??

Comment: There should only be a single `server.properties` file there unless you've made copies of it. What about jps https://stackoverflow.com/a/8249844/2308683